# What is the value of my variable when calling quicksort for the right part?

Tags: java, algorithm, quicksort

I am struggling to understand a specific part in the process of the quick-sort implementation below.

Specifically, when I have sorted the left part of the pivot, I should call `sort(..)` for the right half with arguments j+1 to hi.

Isn't my *j* modified by the partition function when I was using it to sort the left half?

Thus *j+1* isn't actually to the right of the pivot? I guess this is more a question about understanding program flow.

So, what is *j* when I call `sort(a, j+1, hi)`? Sorry if this is a stupid question

```
// sort in ascending order
public static void sort(Comparable[] a) {
    sort(a, 0, a.length - 1);
}

private static void sort(Comparable[] a, int lo, int hi) {
    if (hi <= lo) {
        return;
    }
    int j = partition(a, lo, hi); 
    sort(a, lo, j-1); // Sort left part a[lo .. j-1].
    sort(a, j+1, hi); // <---- issue understanding here
}

private static int partition(Comparable[] a, int lo, int hi) {
    // Partition into a[lo..i-1], a[i], a[i+1..hi].
    int i = lo, j = hi+1; // left and right scan indices
    Comparable v = a[lo]; // partitioning item
    while (true)
    { // Scan right, scan left, check for scan complete, and exchange.
        while (less(a[++i], v)) if (i == hi) break;
        while (less(v, a[--j])) if (j == lo) break;
        if (i >= j) break;
        exch(a, i, j);
    }
    exch(a, lo, j); // Put v = a[j] into position
    return j; // with a[lo..j-1] <= a[j] <= a[j+1..hi].
}
```

When sorting [7, 5, 1, 3, 9, 8], I choose the pivot to be `a[0]=7`. 
Sorting the left half, I get [1,3,5,7,9,8], and now it remains to call sort for the 
right half of the pivot (7). The call -should- look like `sort(a, 3+1, 5)`, but I get 
that it looks like `sort(a, 1+1, 5)` because my *j* was 1 after sorting the left half.

Comment: Your variable values will not be modified if you call a method using them as parameters. Their **state** might be modified, if the value of the variable supports it (i.e. the value is an array, or a set, or some other class with fields that can be assigned to). So no, *value* of `j` will not change after calling `sort(a, lo, j - 1);`.

Comment: This is a variation of Hoare partition scheme. With this scheme, the pivot and elements equal to the pivot can end up anywhere in a sub-array, and when that happens neither a[j] or a[j+1] hold the pivot. This partition method only guarantees that values <= pivot will be left of j+1, and values >= pivot will be right of j.